# How to set a countdown timer to a cookie expire date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, timer

What would be a good way to do a count down timer of a cookie expire date ?
I'm working on an static html page, and I'm having problem to find how to actually do that, something like this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PKWXw/110/)) should be fine for what i need, the problem comes on setting the seconds left after the cookie is setted, no idea on how to do that. Take note, the timer and "set the cookie" will be in different pages. Hope you can give me some tips or ideas.

JS fiddle code:

```
<script>
    //count down function

var seconds_left = 10;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('timer_div').innerHTML = --seconds_left;

    if (seconds_left <= 0)
    {
       document.getElementById('timer_div').innerHTML = "You are Ready!";
       clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);

//set the cookie funcion

    function music_player(){
    days=1; // number of days to keep the cookie
    myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    document.cookie = 'music_player=play; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();
    }
</script>

<a href="#" class="yes_alive" onclick="music_player()">Set the cookie</a>
<div id="timer_div"></div>
```

Comment: I see that your count down timer works just fine.  Is the cookie being set?

Comment: Maybe I've expresses myself bad, I'm asking if that'd be a good way or  if there's a better one, or for a tips/idea/help on how i should do that, i mean to manage the expire date and be able to play with it on the countdown function, the jsfiddle is just to let you understand with what I'm going to work, like a sketch, nothing more.

Comment: I will work up a basic design for you when I get a chance unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: thanks! very kind of you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have an idea of what you are trying to achieve. I have made a few changes that will help you towards your overall goal. When you click on the link the count down timer will start based on the number of seconds you have set for your cookie expiration.

Live Preview: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/bEroPg

HTML:

```
 <div id='timer_div'></div>

<a href="#" id="yes_alive" >Set the cookie</a>
<div id="timer_div"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
//store the number of days
var days = 1;

//store the number of seconds
var seconds_left = days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

//register the  click event
document.getElementById("yes_alive").addEventListener("click", function(event) {

  //stop default action of the anchor tag
  event.preventDefault();

  //call the music player and set the cookie
  music_player(days);

  //start the count down timer
  startTimer(seconds_left);

});

function startTimer(seconds_left) {

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('timer_div').innerHTML = --seconds_left;

    if (seconds_left <= 0) {
      document.getElementById('timer_div').innerHTML = "You are Ready!";
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000);

}

function music_player(days) {

  myDate = new Date();
  myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  document.cookie = 'music_player=play; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();

}
```

Comment: Cool, but if page is reloaded the countdown isn't working anymore, also the timer and "set the cookie" will be in different pages. Anyway thanks for your work! Maybe playing around with the current time and the cookie's expire date ?